# Minimize, Maximize, Close icons not showing in GNOME

Tags: kali-linux, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, window

Minimize, Maximize, Close icons are missing in my GNOME desktop of Kali Linux. However, when I click in the place they are supposed to be, they do what they are supposed to do.

[image: This is what all my windows look like.]

Weirdly, Firefox is only missing the maximize icon!

This may have been caused when I tried to install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. This apparently removed `kali-desktop-gnome` but I could use gnome even after running the installing synaptics. Anyway, I installed `kali-desktop-gnome` again (which automatically removed `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` but the issue is still here.

PS: I would also like to know if it is possible to install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` without removing gnome because I want to enable my touchpad tap to click (`synclient tapbutton1=1`) in xfce too.

Edit: Minimize and Maximize options are already enabled in Gnome Tweaks. Added as per requested by [@iaeiou](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/440770/iaeiou).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same problem on arch. Simply reinstalled `gnome-shell` and updated.

Comment: for confused peeps coming here with xfce instead of gnome, try running `xfwm4`

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

more from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651347/how-to-bring-back-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-in-gnome-3) thread

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux SE, Mathias! Do you mean that there is a typo in [Santiago Echevarria's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630473/423679)? If so, it would be great to suggest an edit to that answer, so that we have it right. See: [How does editing work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Comment: Don't mind me, I didn't look around well enough before posting my answer. I can edit it anyway, the upvotes must have come from the link not necessarily the answer I posted. And besides Mathias is new to the world of Stacks!

Answer (score 2):

Try out this gsettings command and see if it restarts the buttons

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button.layout ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: `rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions`

Comment: Could you possibly explain why this would help and what the issue is that this particular solution solves that none of the other solves?

Comment: this one totally worked for me, I'm using in VirtualBox and I had to add the machine from a previous state

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal and enter
`xfwm4&`
The command restarts the windows manager and backgrounds the process

Comment: Please edit your answer and describe what this command is and how it will help.

Answer (score -2):

Open a terminal and enter

```
xfwm4
```

then press enter. This should restart your window manager and recover your buttons

Comment: This would work in XFCE, not GNOME.

Answer (score -3):

I was having the same problem: minimize/maximize/close buttons disappear like the screenshot above.

The temporary solution that I got was the command `xfwm4`. It solves the problem temporarily but when I reboot, the problem still occurs so the permanent solution to Xfce Desktop is not yet discovered I think ...

So I installed GNOME Desktop. It works well you don't lose any files and it is very attractive so don't waste your time trying to solve the Xfce Desktop problem permanently - let it go and start using GNOME.

Comment: The posted question asks for help with issues in GNOME, not XFCE. They can't switch to GNOME because they are already using GNOME desktop.